# Reflecting changes to a variable in the caller in Java

Tags: java, object, parameters

I have a function that is supposed to return a place object, but I also need to test on whether something evaluates to false, and in addition the caller needs to know both of those pieces of information. I have the return type as Place but in Java there are no reference parameters, so if the following if-condition is true, I would like for some way to reflect that in the caller so I can check it, but I can't have more than one return type so I'm stuck as to what to do. My best shot was returning null but I just get the feeling that this is bad programming.

if ( directions.get(i).isLocked() )

Below is the complete function:

```
Place followDirection(String dir, boolean isLocked) { 
        dir = dir.toLowerCase(); // make sure the string is lowercase for comparisons

        int i = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < directions.size(); i++ ) { // loop until we find a match, remember that if it's locked then we cnanot go in there
            if ( directions.get(i).getDirection().equals(dir) ) {
                if ( directions.get(i).isLocked() ) {
                    System.out.println("This room is locked, sorry");
                }
                else {
                    return directions.get(i).getToPlace(); // this means we found a match, return the destination

                }
            }
        }

        Place p = null;
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: *but I just get the feeling that this is bad programming* - why? Maybe your method should be called `GetNextDirection` and to return `null` if there is no next direction

Comment: Actually this is my teachers' method name, lol. Oh, that brings up a good point. So if I'm testing for three things, returning null has to be disinguished into either it's locked or there is no more directions in the vector. So now I definitely need something similar to a reference parameter

Comment: It would seem a perfect case for throwing Exceptions.  If they're "error" cases, then you should throw an Exception, rather than return an invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there are two options if you don't want to return null (which does not seem bad by the way):

1. return an object that contains both return values
2. Pass in a mutable object as parameter.

The second option also feels somewhat dirty.

Comment: hmm, maybe that's what his `unused` parameter `boolean isLocked` is for

Comment: I can think of three more: 1) return an `Optional<Place>`, 2) return a distinguished value (not `null`) that means "no place", 3) throw a checked exception

Answer (score 0):

java is a call by value language but it is a little bit complicated. this language pass the pointers as a value and if you dont change the pointer you can change the object that pass to your function. for example if you pass an complex object to a function and in that function you change the value of a parameter of that object, the caller can see it, in your code you can pass an object than contains dir and isLocked , so you can change those parameters.

```
Place followDirection(MyObject obj) { 
        obj.dir = obj.dir.toLowerCase(); // make sure the string is lowercase for comparisons

        int i = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < directions.size(); i++ ) { // loop until we find a match, remember that if it's locked then we cnanot go in there
            if ( directions.get(i).getDirection().equals(obj.dir) ) {
                if ( directions.get(i).isLocked() ) {
                    System.out.println("This room is locked, sorry");
                }
                else {
                    return directions.get(i).getToPlace(); // this means we found a match, return the destination

                }
            }
        }

        Place p = null;
        return p;
    }
```

MyObject contains :

```
String dir, boolean isLocked
```

Comment: Mutable arguments are usually an anti-pattern

Comment: @billjamesdev reference and Mutable are passed by value you can still access the object that it refers to but if you replace the reference then you are 'refering' to a different object and that has no effect outside the method.